# Drop down menu going past the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a [previous Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552565/layering-css-blocks-clicks) I had some issues setting up two drop down menus to stay at the top of a page, while a list being scrolled. I have everything set up now, but one of my drop down menus is so long that it extends past the bottom of the page:

[image]

I cant scroll any further to see the last value fully. If it helps I am using this JavaScript library:

http://materializecss.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could put overflow-y:scroll; on the containing div.
I'm going to take a peek at the last question, but I'm pretty sure that will do what you're wanting.

edit:

here is a js fiddle with an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/512263gx/

```
.row {
   background: pink;
   height: 45px;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 10;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

- the div should let you scroll down.

Comment: So is this going on my body or the div containing the drop down?

Comment: It should be the div containing the drop down.

Comment: The other question has has me taking off the overflow-y. It does not work with that property.

Comment: the other question has you taking off overflow:hidden; which hides the content, overflow-y:scroll; lets you scroll the y-axis overflow.

Comment: So when I add that, my drop downs are not visible.... Check out the image here: http://postimg.org/image/5gh3srn5h/e83a68ed/

Comment: do you have a height on that container? Try height:100%;
Since it's fixed it will go 100% of the window width from where it's positioned.

Comment: After playing around this is actually not the answer. Once height was made 100% it covers the list below it and makes the items not clickable.

Comment: You will probably want to do a multi-tier nav instead. Ex :http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/