# Drop down menu going past the end of the page

Tags: html, css, menu

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title> </title>
</head>




<style>

 

* {

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

/* margin around the top margin box */

body {

  margin: 0;

}

 

.navbarRegion {
    
  width:100%;
    
  background-color: #333;
    
  position: relative;
      
  display: flex;
    
}

 

.navbarRegion a {



  font-size: 16px;

  color: white;

  text-align: center;

  padding: 14px 16px;

  text-decoration: none;

}

 

.HRdropdown {


    
    

}

 

.HRdropdown .HRdropbtn {

  font-size: 16px; 

  border: none;

  outline: none;

  color: white;

  padding: 14px 16px;

  background-color: inherit;

  font: inherit;

  margin: 0;

  width:100%;

}

 

.navbarRegion a:hover, .HRdropdown:hover .HRdropbtn {

  background-color: blue;

  cursor: pointer;

  }

 

.HRdropdown-content {

  display: none;

  position: absolute;

   /* #f9f9f9 is grey */

  /* background-color: #f9f9f9; */

  width: 100%;

  left: 0;
  top:100%;

  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

  z-index: 1;
  
    
  background-color: #ccc;  
        

}

 

.HRdropdown-content .L2header {

  /* #4f98ffis blue */

  background: #4f98ff;

  padding: 10px;

  color: white;

   
}

 

.HRdropdown:hover .HRdropdown-content {

  display: block;


}

 

/* Three equal NavColumns which float next to each other */

.NavColumn {


    margin:0;    
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow:1;

    padding: 5px;

    background-color: #ccc;

    /* Controls the height of the shading of the menu items box */

    padding-bottom:2em;

}

 

.NavColumn a {

  float: none;

  color: black;

   /* Control space between menu items */

  padding: 5px;

  text-decoration: none;

  display: block;

  text-align: left;

}

 

.NavColumn a:hover {

   /* Controls the colour of the hover */

  background-color: #ddd;


}

 

/* Clear floats after the NavColumns */

.NavRow {


        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;

}

 

/* Responsive layout - makes the three NavColumns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.NavRow {
    flex-direction: column;
    }
    
  .NavColumn {

    flex-basis: 100%;

    height: auto;

  }

}

 

</style> 
<body>
<div class="navbarRegion"> 
   <a href="https://rollsroyce.sharepoint.com/sites/engineroom/en-gb/hr/Pages/default.aspx">Home</a>
      <div class="HRdropdown"> 
         <button class="HRdropbtn">UK 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> </button> 
         <div class="HRdropdown-content"> 
            <div class="L2header"> 
               <h3>My heading </h3> 
            </div> 
            <div class="NavRow"> 
               <div class="NavColumn"> 
                  <h3>First heading</h3> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  </div> 
                <div class="NavColumn"> 
                  <h3>Second heading</h3> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  </div> 
                <div class="NavColumn"> 
                  <h3>Third heading</h3> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  </div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="NavRow"> 
               <div class="NavColumn"> 
                  <h3>First heading</h3> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  </div> 
                <div class="NavColumn"> 
                  <h3>Second heading</h3> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  </div> 
                <div class="NavColumn"> 
                  <h3>Third heading</h3> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  </div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="NavRow"> 
               <div class="NavColumn"> 
                  <h3>First heading</h3> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  </div> 
                <div class="NavColumn"> 
                  <h3>Second heading</h3> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  </div> 
                <div class="NavColumn"> 
                  <h3>Third heading</h3> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  <a href="#">Menu item </a> 
                  </div> 
            </div> 
            <
         </div> 
      </div> 
      <!-- END OF UK SECTION --> 
         
            
            
            
            </div> 
<div style="padding: 16px;"> 
   <h3>Our menu</h3>
      <br/>
  <p>Welcome ... etc </p>
      <br/>
      <br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've got my menu system working but the "UK" menu is quite long and disappears when you mouse off the bottom.  It is okay with a scroll wheel on a mouse, but I need the user to be able to hover over items as they move down the menu.
I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556288/drop-down-menu-going-past-the-bottom-of-page), but I don't think it helps.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: could you clarify this "but I need the user to be able to hover over items as they move down the menu."?

Comment: So at the moment, the menu is quite long, and you can scroll down if you use the mouse scroll wheel, which allows you to see the whole of the menu. However, if you are using a trackpad, and move the mouse to the bottom of the menu, the menu disappears

Comment: I’d really appreciate it if anyone can help me. @NicoShultz

Comment: I’d really appreciate it if anyone can help me. https://stackoverflow.com/users/6034220/nico-shultz